# How can I create this abstract, folded, smooth black & white lines effect?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, effects, texture

I'm trying to recreate this type of effect:

[image]

My first guess was the Warp tool in Illustrator (I want this in vector) but I get gaps between the black and white lines so I don't think this is the approach. Any tips?

Comment: Why do you need white lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also get more refined or closer to perfect lines if you use BLEND to transition from one line to the next. It might be quicker too because you only need to draw 2 lines possibly.

I would create the top line and then the last line and then select both lines and select on the menu: Object / Blend / Make.

Now you can go to Object / Blend / Blend Options to make changes to how the lines blend.

Once the multiple lines are created then you can do as SaraB says by creating a box around all of the lines and then following steps 6 and 7:

1. Now, select everything (Ctrl+A) and use the Pathfinder tool and
   choose "Divide".
2. Right-click and choose "Ungroup." You now have
   individual shapes that you can alternately color black and white (or
   whatever colors you choose.) If you Ctrl+Shift-click every other
   shape you can color them all at together at the same time.

Hope this helps.

Chris

Answer (score 6):

I'm sure there are other ways to go about this, but this is how I successfully created this effect in just a few minutes.

[image]

1. Begin with a solid white or black shape. (I used a square.)
2. Then, I would draw the lines using the pen tool across the shape to
   create the flow of the design. I'd turn off fill and use whatever
   color stroke you like. (The stroke will help you see what you are
   doing and won't appear in the final design.) I created a very quick
   example myself, but you can take more time/care to lay these lines
   out in an interesting and aesthetically appealing manner. I began by
   creating one curvy line across the middle of the rectangle.
3. I then Alt-clicked the line and dragged a copy below that one.
4. I adjusted the curves just a tiny bit as I saw fit.
5. I continued to copy/paste and adjust these lines until my entire
   shape was completely covered.
6. Now, select everything (Ctrl+A) and use the Pathfinder tool and
   choose "Divide".
7. Right-click and choose "Ungroup." You now have individual shapes
   that you can alternately color black and white (or whatever colors
   you choose.) If you Ctrl+Shift-click every other shape you can color
   them all at together at the same time.